# facebook type left slide bar layout should appear in all view controllers

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, facebook

I have implemented Facebook type left Slide Bar layout in my first view of iphone app. Now, I want to implement this throughout all view controllers (screens) in application, means irrespective of the view the left slide bar should appear on clicking the menu button at the top in all views.

My app contains 25-30 viewcontrollers and my slide bar layout should appear in all views..

Can anyone suggest, how can I include above FB Layout in all views

Thanks in advance

Ramu

Comment: I don't see any valid point by implementing a Facebook type slide bar layout on your own. There are many open source slider menus that you can use in you project. Just check the below link. http://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/ddmenucontroller. If you really need to use your code you can get the idea by looking at source code of existing menus.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem. I was using a facebook-style menu, and needed it in all view controllers.

You can use a Container Controller. A Container Controller can have the base layout, which I defined in a nib, containing a navigation bar and a bar button item to toggle the menu, and then add child view controllers and remove them as you need them. That way, you can throw whatever view controller you need to the container controller and it will display it.

You can also add gesture control to slide open/close the menu easily.

You will have to make the Container controller your self, it is not standard. I think it is better solution than inheritance, since if you use inheritance you can't make a for example UITableViewController, all your controllers will be of the type of yuor master class. Of course, you can fix this anyway with delegates.

It may sound a bit tricky, but see this tutorial which I used: http://www.cocoanetics.com/2012/04/containing-viewcontrollers/

It wasn't accutally that hard.

EDIT: You can just use a UINavigationController as well. Just set the base view controller to the view controller you want to display, and you can prevent it adding the back button etc to the nav bar by overriding the default methods. Make a UINavigationController as `rootNavigationController`. Might be simpler.

Answer (score 4):

Simple, The one view controller in which you have implemented the `FB layout` and is working. Make it the base class on top of `UIViewController`. And as for the rest of all the ViewControllers, inherit them from the MasterClass that you just created. Doing this will make the swipe gesture that brings forth the slide bar available to all of your 30 view controllers.

**EDIT**

Lets see, we have UIViewController, now first of all you create a UIViewController's subclass: say FBViewController ..In this FBViewController you implement the FBLayout such that the swipe  and all is working ..on it ..test your app first using only this FBViewController as rootViewController and check all the functionalities.Once everything is working fine, grow on it. What I mean is this.

Say you are creating a Tabbed application, where all the three tabs are supposed to have the same FBLayout style. Then do these steps.

1. Create FBViewController, it inherits from UIViewController (using UIViewController subclass template, also check the generate XIB button) also have an XIB for it FBViewController.XIB (fully implement FBLayout in it. This will be your base class)
2. Then Create three more ViewController classes (FirstViewController, SecondViewController, ThirdViewController) again from the UIViewController subclass template, but for these three dont check the generate XIB button. these three will use the XIB of the base class FBViewController (If you are wondering how, then go to step 3 :))
3. Go to header file of FirstViewController class you created, there you can see `@interface FirstViewController: UIViewController` replace it with `@interface FirstViewController: FBViewController`, but before it import FBViewController.h to the header file. Repeat the same for the Other two classes- SecondViewController, ThirdViewController. Since these three will inherit from FBViewController. In their `viewDidLoad` `[super viewDidLoad]` will load FBViewController and generate the view. after `[super viewDidLoad];` line you can implement ur own methods.
4. In the three classes just change the `initWithNibName` method to change the tab bar name and title.
5. In appDelegate go to `didFinishLaunching` method and put these three view controller in a `tabBarController`, set the `tabBarController` as rootViewController.

And we are done. If your `FBViewController` is working fine. You will see that all the three classes behave the same way. Thanx to the power of Inheritance.

Cheers, play a bit, have fun.

Comment: Hi @croyneaus4u, I am not getting you..Could you please elaborate. Please give me a prototype to work for. I am just getting started on objective-c and iphone app development.

Comment: Hi @croyneaus4u, thanks for detail explanation. I am able to get that as you suggested. But, in above method I have a problem. In implemented facebook layout when clicking/toggle top layer, bottom  layer should appear. So, I had two views in single view controller. Now when I want navigate to another view controller, only my top layer should navigate. Is it possible the bottom layer should remain constant across all view controllers. Thanks for reply..

Comment: looking at your requirement, following the containment policy would be much better, as suggested by @kjelelokk. to navigate only a part of th e view, you better use one view controller as container. And from their add and remove other viewControllers as child controllers and their respective views. And also add the animation for removal and addition

Answer (score 2):

I'd highly recommend using an open source solution that handles all the edge cases for you - it's both the easiest, most robust and most maintainable (since the community will keep it up to date fro you). [ViewDeck](https://github.com/Inferis/ViewDeck) seems to be the most popular solution though I have also had success with [PPRevealSideViewController](https://github.com/ipup/PPRevealSideViewController). They both provide a very robust implementation that would take a long time to do yourself (e.g. you can optionally enable swipe on the navigation bar or even content area to open the menu). Furthermore they separate the sliding logic and the revealed menu (which can be any view controller you like, but most likely a table view controller) out of your other view controllers. That way any viewcontroller can have a side menu without duplicating any code - separation of concern is great :)

Answer (score 1):

You can make a SharedInstance for SideView class. I am doing same thing for iAD to show throught-out the application. 
Please see the the link of iAdSuite ,In which the BannerViewController is SharedInstance so they are easily used for all View Controller

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/iAdSuite/Listings/TabbedBanner_TabbedBanner_BannerViewController_m.html